# well known error correcting code correcting 2 errors

Tags: coding-theory

I know that the Hamming (7,4) code is 1-error correcting. 
Are there any well-known error correcting code which can correct up to 2 errors?

Comment: what about Reed-Solomon codes? You can construct RS codes with arbitrary ability, if I'm not mistaken. They are also well known, since implemented everywhere.

Comment: @Martin how about binary codes?

Comment: I don't know any for exactly 2. More than one, yes, Hadamard codes for example, but I guess they either correct 1 or more than 3 errors, since their distance is a power of 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 5-fold repetition code --- the code that encodes 0 as 00000, and 1 as 11111 --- corrects any 2 errors. I wouldn't recommend using it, what with its very low rate, but it does answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

BCH codes can be designed to correct any number of errors. The (15,7) code can correct up to 2 bit errors.